How does adding an optional field to an existing protobuf message affect serialization
Say I have the following protobuf definition:
message SomeMessage {
  required string required_field = 1;
}

and I create the following object:
val someMessage = SomeMessage(required_field = "required field")

And this message is used as a key for accessing data that's stored in some cache.
Now, I want to add a new, optional field, to this message:
message SomeMessage {
  required string required_field = 1;
  optional string optional_field = 2;
}

and create a new object (based on the new protobuf schema) with the same data:
val someNewMessage = SomeMessage(required_field = "required field")

Will both objects have the same serializition (i.e. if I use both of them to access the cache, will both return the same entry?)?
